# Like button that can update database without refreshing page

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've got a like button, which holds an ID from a database. I'm trying click the like button, update a database and then it'll switch to unlike without reloading the page.

I'll paste the code below, so you have an understanding:

**index.php:
**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Like Button Function
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".likeBtn").on("click", function(){
        
        var threadID = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(threadID);

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "like_function.php",
             data: threadID,
             success:function(html)
             {
             }
        });

        });
    });

</script>
<form action='javascript:void(0);' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type='submit' name='likeBtn' class='likeBtn' id='52' value='Like'>
</form>
```

So the var threadID = retrieving an ID from database (I used 52 as example)
From here, I want to be able to run a php script (like_function.php) to update database using the ID stored as a variable.

Lastly, I want that button to change to unlike. Sorry for being a noob at this. I'm new to Ajax

Comment: Do you use vanilla PHP or some framework?

Comment: What is your DB schema to store likes?

Comment: I'm storing in MYSQL db and the type as 'text'. Everytime the button is clicked, it'll update the column with that IP. And then if your IP is stored, it'll display an unlike button.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: change input type submit to input type button. input type submit actually submits a form which will refresh your page

Comment: I see a lot of statements made but no question being asked. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `preventDefault()` to cancel the event `submit` and now you can update your data. Example below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".likeBtn").on("click", function(e){ // set e in arguments
        
        e.preventDefault(); // use this
        var threadID = $(this).attr("id"); // [...]
```